# Dimension Roll-Up in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have an OLAP cube that contains financial information of our offices. In the underlying tables, we calculate lifecycle phases of offices by using each office’s average weekly revenue. The lifecycle phases are calculated on week ending date level. For ex:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grGFe.png)

Here is the MDX that generates the above example:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Current Period Revenue] } ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY { ([04 - Office - Financial].[Office Name and Number].[Office Name and Number].ALLMEMBERS * [01 - Journal Date].[Quarter].[Quarter].ALLMEMBERS * [01 - Journal Date].[Week Ending Date].[Week Ending Date].ALLMEMBERS * [04 - Office Lifecycle].[Office Life Cycle Phase].[Office Life Cycle Phase].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [01 - Journal Date].[Year].&[2020] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [04 - Office - Financial].[Office Name and Number].&[Office A] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [GL Cube])) 
WHERE ( [01 - Journal Date].[Year].&[2020] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

In the cube, the office and office lifecycle are two different dimensions. In the above example, Office A has two different phases through Qtr 2 2020: Phase1 and Phase 2. The last week ending date of Qtr 2020 shows Phase 2 for this office.
When we take out the Week Ending Date from the pivot table, the cube again shows Phase 1 and Phase 2 for Qtr 2 2020:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORjRr.png)

MDX:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Current Period Revenue] } ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY { ([04 - Office - Financial].[Office Name and Number].[Office Name and Number].ALLMEMBERS * [01 - Journal Date].[Quarter].[Quarter].ALLMEMBERS * [04 - Office Lifecycle].[Office Life Cycle Phase].[Office Life Cycle Phase].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [01 - Journal Date].[Year].&[2020] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [04 - Office - Financial].[Office Name and Number].&[Office A] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [GL Cube])) 
WHERE ( [01 - Journal Date].[Year].&[2020] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Is there a way to adjust the cube, so it would reflect only the office life cycle phase of the last week of a quarter? In this case, the pivot table would look like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO46I.png)

Is there a way to do achieve this kind of a dynamic dimension behavior in the cube?

Comment: Can you share the DAX or MDX query you are using to generate that matrix?

Comment: hi @vvvv4d  I added MDX queries to the question, thanks!